# Issue with localhost:8888 downloading file and not showing "create configuration file" option

Tags: wordpress, localhost, mamp

After I install wordpress and go to localhost:8888 and click on the link shown under "index of" I am getting a file that my computer downloads and not the "create configuration file". Could you please shed some light on what is going wrong? Thank you! ﻿

Comment: Have you installed WordPress in /htdocs folder?

Comment: Yes I have WordPress in the htdocs folder but I first fallowed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sNRBnX6CtXE and it recommended I make my own folder and place it on my desktop. So now I have WordPress both in this new folder and in my htdocs which I'm not sure if that matters or not. Forgive me if I sound lame this is my first time using MAMP and themes for WordPress